# Getting Errors while updating my Angular project to angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

While trying to update my existing Angular project to angular 7, 
I got following errors.

```
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet.d.ts(8,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay'.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet.d.ts(9,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'.
node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts(8,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/button.d.ts(8,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/button.d.ts(9,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.
node_modules/@angular/material/checkbox/typings/checkbox.d.ts(8,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip-list.d.ts(8,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip-list.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip-list.d.ts(10,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/collections'.
node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip.d.ts(8,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip.d.ts(9,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.
node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/datetime/native-date-adapter.d.ts(8,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.
node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/ripple/ripple-renderer.d.ts(9,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.
node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/ripple/ripple.d.ts(8,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/calendar.d.ts(8,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/datepicker.d.ts(8,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/datepicker.d.ts(9,53): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay'.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/datepicker.d.ts(10,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/month-view.d.ts(10,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/multi-year-view.d.ts(10,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/year-view.d.ts(10,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-config.d.ts(9,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-config.d.ts(10,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay'.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-container.d.ts(10,84): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-container.d.ts(11,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-ref.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay'.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts(8,59): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay'.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts(9,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/accordion-base.d.ts(9,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/accordion'.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/accordion.d.ts(9,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/accordion'.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel-header.d.ts(8,60): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel.d.ts(9,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/accordion'.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel.d.ts(10,43): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/collections'.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel.d.ts(11,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'.
node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/typings/form-field.d.ts(8,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/typings/form-field.d.ts(18,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.
node_modules/@angular/material/grid-list/typings/grid-list.d.ts(10,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/input/typings/autosize.d.ts(8,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/text-field'.
node_modules/@angular/material/input/typings/input.d.ts(8,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.
node_modules/@angular/material/input/typings/input.d.ts(9,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/text-field'.
node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts(8,50): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/collections'.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-directive.d.ts(8,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-directive.d.ts(9,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-item.d.ts(8,60): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-panel.d.ts(10,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-panel.d.ts(11,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-trigger.d.ts(8,43): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-trigger.d.ts(9,43): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-trigger.d.ts(10,41): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay'.
node_modules/@angular/material/progress-spinner/typings/progress-spinner.d.ts(8,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.
node_modules/@angular/material/radio/typings/radio.d.ts(8,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/radio/typings/radio.d.ts(9,43): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/collections'.
node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts(8,59): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts(10,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/collections'.
node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts(11,62): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay'.
node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts(12,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/scrolling'.
node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav/typings/drawer.d.ts(9,61): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav/typings/drawer.d.ts(10,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav/typings/drawer.d.ts(11,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.
node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav/typings/drawer.d.ts(12,64): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/scrolling'.
node_modules/@angular/material/sidenav/typings/sidenav.d.ts(10,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/scrolling'.
node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts(8,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts(10,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.
node_modules/@angular/material/slider/typings/slider.d.ts(8,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/slider/typings/slider.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar-config.d.ts(9,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar-config.d.ts(10,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar-container.d.ts(9,84): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'.
node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar-ref.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay'.
node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar.d.ts(8,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar.d.ts(9,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/layout'.
node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar.d.ts(10,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/overlay'.
node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar.d.ts(11,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'.
node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/step-header.d.ts(8,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/step-header.d.ts(13,42): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/stepper'.
node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/step-label.d.ts(8,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/stepper'.
node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper-button.d.ts(8,52): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/stepper'.
node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper-icon.d.ts(9,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/stepper'.
node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts(8,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts(9,53): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/stepper'.
node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/cell.d.ts(9,117): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/table'.
node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/row.d.ts(8,97): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/table'.
node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/table-data-source.d.ts(8,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/table'.
node_modules/@angular/material/table/typings/table.d.ts(8,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/table'.
node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-body.d.ts(10,70): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/portal'.
node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-body.d.ts(11,43): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-header.d.ts(8,43): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/material/tabs/typings/tab-header.d.ts(9,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/
```

Comment: Can you share your app.module.ts and package.json files

Comment: please format the stacktrace

Comment: do you update your deps and install all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this in terminal `npm install @angular/cdk --save` and `npm install @angular/material --save`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the dependencies. Make sure you install the required modules by running `npm install`.

If the `@angular/cdk` and `@angular/material` are not in your `package.json` dependencies and you are using it.. add them and install dependencies before running project.